# Javascript - Remove Special characters and associated strings in Json object

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, pattern-matching

i'm trying to fix and get expected result but am failed.

```
let sample obj= 
[{ profile: admin, availableAction: 'You have [Access: write][Option: print] only few options'},
{ profile: cust, availableAction: 'You have [Access: write][Option: print] only few options'}
]
```

i want to print only `'You have only few options'`

to achive this, i tried below possible way but failed

```
  for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log('KEY---->', key + ' -> ' + obj[key]);

          if (obj.includes('[Access: write][Option: print] ')) {
            obj = obj.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, '');
          }
      }
  }
```

but getting cannot read property error.

could some one tell me how to fix this properly.

Note: I know its duplicate thread, i tried as much as possible solution from SO. but couldn't make use of it effectively.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of a [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) function that can be passed to `JSON.stringify`. After stringification you can parse the JSON string back to an object using `JSON.parse`

```js
let obj = [
  { profile: "admin", availableAction: 'You have [Access: write][Option: print] only few options'},
  { profile: "cust", availableAction: 'You have [Access: write][Option: print] only few options'}
];



const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) =>
  (k === "availableAction") 
    ? v.replace('[Access: write][Option: print] ', '') 
    : v
));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks alot man, you save my day. could you pls tell me why my regex not at all helped?

Comment: No problem. Your regex was fine, the root cause of the issue was that you referenced the object (`obj`) instead of the object property (`obj[key]`) in the second if statement. If you modify it correspondingly: `if (obj[key].includes('[Access: write][Option: print] ')) obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/\[(.*)\]/, '');` it should work as expected.

Comment: thanks again for your explanation and for your solution :)